# Detect device motion with respect to gravity

Tags: android, gravity, motion-detection

I am trying to build an App where I want to  detect the motion of device.
Basically I need to detect the fall of device.
Can anyone help me on how can I do this Using accelerometer with respect to Gravity?

Answer (score 0):

the high-pass filter must be used.If we filter out the slow changing forces like gravity by using a high-pass filter then the remaining forces are the fast changing ones like the forces being applied to the phone in vertical direction.

This is how the components of the acceleration break down into each axis:

```
 values[0] //acceleration on x axis
 values[1] //acceleration on y axis
 values[2] //acceleration on z axis
```

You need to find which direction gravity is operating in then decompose that into its component parts. The magnitude of the gravity force will always be 9.8 but the direction, and hence how it breaks down into the component parts, will change. Assuming that we could get the value of gravity and store that vector in an array like gravity[3]:

```
gravity[0] //gravity x axis
 gravity[1] //gravity y axis
 gravity[2] //gravity z axis

The total acceleration, T, on the phone is T = g + a. To get just a we would need a = T - g:

 linear_acceleration[0] = event.values[0] - gravity[0];
 linear_acceleration[1] = event.values[1] - gravity[1];
 linear_acceleration[2] = event.values[2] - gravity[2];
```

Notice how this calculates everything element by element because it's a vector operation.
after extracting all values we must apply a high pass filter and compare  linear_acceleration[2] with a threshold(maybe u can keep it around 9).